# Why is it not possible for the vector $1$ to be an element in the following subspace of $P_2(R): U = \{f (x) ∈ P_2(R) | f (5) = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the subspace of $P_2(R): U = \{f (x) ∈ P_2(R) | f (5) = 0\}$.

My textbook states: its clear that $U \neq P_2(R)$ since the vector $ 1 \notin U$ but $1 \in P_2$ Therefore $\dim(U) < 3$.

I am wondering why vector $1$ can't be in $U$, with a coefficient of $0$.

I know that the standard basis of $P_2(R)$ is $\{x^2, x, 1\}$.

So if we have coefficients a, b, and c in the form $ax^2 + bx + c(1)$ cant $f(5) = 0$ if $a = 0, b = 1, c = 0$?

Comment: Given $g(x)=0x^2+0x+1$ what is $g(5)$ equal to?  Is $g(5)=0$?  Is $0x^2+0x+1=0$ when $x=5$?  Is $0\cdot 5^2+0\cdot 5 + 1=0$?  What does that mean about $g$?  Is $g$ in your set?

Comment: This is not saying anything about *multiples of $g$* being in or not being in your set.  Sure, $0\cdot g$ will be in your set... but the question is about $g$ itself being in or not being in your set.  Basic arithmetic and understanding shows that $1\neq 0$ and the result follows.

Comment: Compare to the problem of talking about the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ given as $U=\{(a,b,c)~:~25a+5b+c=0\}$ and asking if $(0,0,1)$ is an element of that subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $1$ here is $i(x)=0x^2+0x+1$. When you evaluate it in $5$ get $i(5)=1 \neq 0$ so the condition to be part of $U$ isn't fullfiled.